# Firebase Auth not working on Android Phone - popup flashes

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

In my app I've developer Firebase Auth.

In my emulator (Android Studio), it works fine in all devices, so I've passed on to every phone I could find, and the weirdest thing happens. Every provider I use ( Google, Microsofta and Apple) the popup flashes and disappears right away.

Is there any permission I need to add to my app to get the popups to stay open?

I've already have android:uses:internet in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: Post the code that is related to this issue. Check if any of these devices have something interesting logs (warning, debug) at the moment and right after the popup appeared and closed.

Comment: Can you show your code what you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have not added the release sha-1 key to firebase.
Since it seems to work when using android studio. When you first added the app to firebase, it automatically added the debug sha-1 key.
The release sha-1 key has to be added manually.

Comment: NO! it is not a problem of SHA 1 as if you won't add it firebase will throw an exception

Comment: It was indeed the releass sha-1 key that was missing. Thank you.